# pushwoosh service name of windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, pushwoosh

I want to integrate pushwoosh in my game of windows phone.
 I am not able to understand what is the service name. pushwoosh have provided guide but it is not much useful to understand.

the following is link of the website  [www.pushwoosh.com](http://www.pushwoosh.com)

I downloaded the sdk and integrated into my game but its not working.

It is giving an exception  as following image is showing:

[image]

this is my App.xaml code

```
enter code here <Application 
x:Class="PhoneApp2.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
 xmlns:PushSDK="clr-namespace:PushSDK;assembly=PushSDK"
   xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

>

<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
</Application.Resources>

<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService Activated="Application_Activated"
                                        Closing="Application_Closing"
                                        Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"
                                        Launching="Application_Launching">
        <!--  PushWoosh application ID  -->
        <PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService.PWAppId>498DE-98D2F</PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService.PWAppId>

        <!--  Page on which the navigation is when receiving toast push notification. Note: Full path.  -->
        <PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService.PushPage>c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PhoneApp2\PhoneApp2\pushmsg.xaml</PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService.PushPage>

        <!--  Page on which the navigation is when receiving toast push notification.  -->
        <PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService.ServiceName>pushmsg</PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService.ServiceName>

        <!--  Tile trusted servers  -->
        <PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService.TileTrustedServers>
            <System:String>http://www.pushwoosh.com</System:String>
        </PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService.TileTrustedServers>

    </PushSDK:PhonePushApplicationService>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error was coming because i was using the same pushwoosh sdk  which was previously used for project.
means if once the pushsdk.dll is used by one project then it runs in processes
 so that error was coming.

now i use fresh pushdsdk for each project and its working well!!